# What is the private key and what is public?

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

This question seems simplistic, but I'm studying for the 70-483 C# exam and getting a little confused.

I understand that Public/Private keys are mathmatically interlinked properties. One can encrypt a message, the other can decrypt.

Everything I read e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-public-key-cryptography-work), [codeproject](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-symmetric-and-asymmetric-cryptography-algorithms-with-c-sharp/) shows the public key being used to encrypt and private key to decrypt.

However, the practice exam I'm working on (MeasureUp) seems to change which is used.

Sometimes the answers state to use the pubic key to encrypt, BUT sometimes they state to use the private key.

Example:

> The application must communicate securely with the DMV. The DMV must
>   be sure that data sent from your application was not modified in
>   transit.

Answer to example:

> Generate a hash of the data. Encrypt the hash with
>   the *private* key of your company. Send the data and the encrypted
>   hash to the DMV.

The 'Show Answers' part then goes on to explain the above explicitly stating to encrypt with the private key.

Is it just the case that you have to consider what's public and what's private in context?

e.g.

A) If it doesn't matter if other people can see the message just as long as they can't make one of their own - encrypt using the key you "keep private".

B) If other people can make a message, just as long as I'm the only one who can read it - encrypt using the publicly available key.

I feel like MeasureUp might have it wrong, but surely I'm more likely to be wrong than a big company.

Please can someone explain/ provide clarity on why this answer would be correct?

Comment: Cryptographers have allowed some laxness in terminology to creep into everyday usage over the decades, especially because in RSA in particular both signing and encryption use the same basic arithmetic operation, namely modular exponentiation.  It's a shame that an exam would contain this ambiguity, but I can't say I'm surprised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different security scenarios; in *encryption*, you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key; but with *signing*, you sign with the private key, and validate with the public key.

Most likely, the question is about signing, not encryption.

Since the question mentions:

> The DMV must be sure that data sent from your application was not modified in transit.

this is signing (integrity and proof of who authored it), not encryption.

Comment: Thank you. That will be the bit I'm not getting.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. However, that they confuse encryption with signing is a very bad sign

Answer (score 2):

Both keys can be used to en- and decrypt. The difference is: you should be the *only* one to have your private key. Everybody else can have the public key.

So if you encrypt something, everybody can be sure that the **content was sent by you**, because the public key can only successfully decrypt your message if it really was encrypted with your private key.

On the other hand, if someone wants to send you a message that only you can read, they will encrypt it with your public key. So **only you  can decrypt** it again (or someone who stole your private key).